# How do you iterate tuple values in a dictionary for django context

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary

I am trying to push a Django context dictionary to a template.

I have a bunch of values for songs and created a dictionary with tuple values like so:

```
songs = {'titles': ('Hello', 'Umbrella'), 'artists': ('Adele', 'Rihanna')}
```

How do I loop it to output:

```
Hello
Adele

Umbrella
Rihanna
```

Or maybe I should rethink my context dictionary setup?

Comment: As dictionaries have arbitrary order, you'll have to tell us by what logic "Hello" comes before "Adele" and "Umbrella" comes before "Rihanna".

Comment: @timgeb: Because the tuples themselves are ordered.  The titles come before the artists and each title comes before the next.

Comment: @zondo oh, I was assuming the dictionary could have more keys and this was just a sample dict. Nevermind, if it can only ever have those two keys, the order is determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
titles = ('Hello', 'Umbrella')
artists = ('Adele', 'Rihanna')
songs = {'titles_artists': zip(titles, artist)}
```

in your template:

```
{% for title, artist in titles_artists %}
    <p>{{ title }}<br>{{ artist }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can try rethink your context dictionary, something like:

```
songs = {'artists': [
                        {'name': 'Adele', 'titles': ['Hello', ]}, 
                        {'name': 'Rihanna', 'titles': ['Umbrella', ]}
                    ]
        }
```

And in your template:

```
{% for artist in artists %}
    {% for title in artist.titles %}
         {{ title }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ artist.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ya this is more of what I was looking for! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
for title, artist in zip(songs['titles'], songs['artists']):
    print(title)
    print(artist)
    print() # In Python 2, remove the parentheses
```

Comment: You're a godsend. Thanks a lot!